# how to prevent downloading js files from my server

Tags: javascript, security, download

is there a way i can prevent users from downloading my js files from the server ?

i tried htaccess and it only gives 403 error on browsing the files but when i try to download them i easily can.

```
    RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://cbox.ws/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://cbox.ws$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.cbox.ws/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.cbox.ws$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www7.cbox.ws/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www7.cbox.ws$      [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(js|css|php)$ - [F,NC]
```

Regards

Comment: so i really cant understand why i got -2 votes for this when i was just asking for help, some people are just crazy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't. The client needs to be able to access them. So even if you "secured" it somehow people could simply retrieve it from the browser cache or view it using e.g. Firebug.

What you *can* do however is minifying your code. A good minifier obfuscates it (because a one-character variable name is much shorter) so people have a hard time reading it even if they prettify it.